# jQuery currency spinner - "normalization"

Tags: php, jquery, spinner, normalization, currency

I want to use the [jQuery spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#currency) for a currency value (i.e. money), the value of which might be in dollars, euros, or anything supported by the spinner.

The data should then be saved into a mysql database, in one col I would save the currency, in another the value.

The problem is that I am not sure on how to do this. Is it better to save the data in the format provided by the spinner (therefore saving everything as varchar), or should I take the extra step of normalizing all the values in and reconverting according to the currency when out from the db?
Note that I would like to perform some calculations (simple algebra) on that data, but only with values of the same currency.

Comment: use numberFormat() to parse the number formatted how you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do some calculations with the inserted data, it's better to store it without `, . / $`.
And wherever you want to show the data, change it into currency format.